# Developing Android apps from within Android

Tags: apk, development

I want to be able to develop Android applications from my Nexus 6p. Basically, just have a project, and compile it into an installable apk, but from within Android itself.
I have heard of AIDE and Java N-IDE, but neither are satisfactory. The AIDE developers seem to be to greedy for money, and the app rarely works. Java N-IDE cannot seem to compile my app with libraries.

I would prefer to do this from a command line, but it doesn't matter too much. I have adb working on my phone, and I also have aidl and aapt on my phone too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a Premium Key ( Separate App )
I think AIDE Is your best bet !

Comment: I don't have the money. My parents are really controlling of how I use my money. I am rarely allowed to spend any of it.

Comment: PC and Android Studio then, If you don't mind just compiling the apps manually or building the source code with java text editors ( syntax highlighted ) then you just need to copy it to the PC for final build and/or export